# Deduplicating rows ignoring other columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to collect some client data from multiple sources and remove the duplicate IDs, while mantaining the values from the other columns and keeping the True value from the columns which shows where the client came from (it can be from more than one source). I'm having some trouble to create a sql query for that. I've tried coalesce function but the query lasted almost 1 hour to finish (~ 40 million lines).

Example:

Source 1:

| Name | ClientID | Source1 | Source2 | Source3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | 123 | False | True | False |

Source 2:

| Name | ClientID | Source1 | Source2 | Source3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name2 | 123 | True | False | False |

Needed result:

| Name | ClientID | Source1 | Source2 | Source3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 or Name 2 | 123 | True | True | False |

My code:

```
WITH ids AS (
  SELECT id FROM source1
  UNION
  SELECT id FROM source2
  UNION
  SELECT id FROM source3
)

SELECT
  COALESCE(s1.name, s2.name, s3.name) AS name,
  id AS clientid,
  CASE WHEN s1.id IS NULL THEN False ELSE True END AS source1,
  CASE WHEN s2.id IS NULL THEN False ELSE True END AS source2,
  CASE WHEN s3.id IS NULL THEN False ELSE True END AS source3
FROM ids i
LEFT JOIN source1 s1 ON i.id = s1.id
LEFT JOIN source2 s2 ON i.id = s2.id
LEFT JOIN source3 s3 ON i.id = s3.id
```

Comment: Your sample data has no column called `id`.

Comment: If you need any help with indexing, You must provide the estimation plan.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, It's the ClientID column, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `id` is unique in each table, then `full join` is probably the simplest method:

```
select id,
       (case when s1 is not null then 1 else 0 end) as in_source1,
       (case when s2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) as in_source2,
       (case when s3 is not null then 1 else 0 end) as in_source3
from source1 s1 full join
     source2 s2
     using (id) full join
     source3 s3
     using (id);
```

I prefer `0` and `1` instead of `'true'` and `'false'`.

You can also `union all` and aggregate:

```
select id,
       max(in1) as in_source1,
       max(in2) as in_source2,
       max(in3) as in_source3
from ((select id, 1 as in1, 0 as in2, 0 as in3
       from source1 s1
      ) union all
      (select id, 0 as in1, 1 as in2, 0 as in3
       from source1 s1
      ) union all
      (select id, 0 as in1, 0 as in2, 1 as in3
       from source1 s1
      )
     ) s123
group by id;
```